# GDB Debugger Crashes on std::thread spawn

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, qt-creator, stdthread

[image]I write a c++ program with several threads, and it always worked properly. Just since I use QtCreator on  Linux virtual machine the program crashed on spawning a thread with
`my_thread = new std::thread(workerThread, arg);` when using the debugger.
If i run the program without debugging, the thread spawns properly and the program keeps running (I tried it with some log messages). I think it is an issue of the platform, because i didn't change the code somewhere and it doesn't work with any of the threads.
Someone has any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Can you run the debugger from the terminal without it crashing?

Comment: I did it with gdb <executable> and then run. The program does not crash and executes properly.

Comment: This could indicate undefined behaviour. Try building with the sanitizer library and/or run under valgrind.

Comment: Sorry, can you specify a little bit what you mean? Would it be advisable to try another debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Found the same issue in the bug report section of qt, seems to be a general issue. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-25438
Tools>Options>Debugger>GDB and writing "handle SIGSTOP nostop pass" to the debuggers startup commands makes gdb skip the error, but dows not seem like a permanent solution to me